# Copy output string to variable after multiple pipes

Tags: linux, shell

Im trying to store the output of a set of commands to a variable in a shell script. The obvious backticks and eval are failing. Could someone help me out with this.

I want to store the output of

```
head -"$errno" tmptmptmp2 | tail -1 | sed 's/,//'
```

into a variable.

The command works fine BTW.

Comment: Did you try `var=$(head....)` ?

Comment: Yup.. heres what I get for bacticks , eval and $() line 20: =: command not found.

Comment: No need for the head/tail portion of the pipe.  Just do: sed -n "${errno}s/,//p"

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
var=$(head -"$errno" tmptmptmp2 | tail -1 | sed 's/,//')
```